# What's the difference between a Cannondale F29 Carbon 3 and a Cannondale F29 *Flash* Carbon 3?

Tags: cannondale

I'm trying to decide on a mountain bike and I've short-listed the Cannondale F29 Carbon 3.

Some bike shops are listing them as [F29 Carbon 3 **Flash**](http://www.tredz.co.uk/.Cannondale-Flash-Carbon-29er-3-Mountain-Bike-2013-Hardtail-Race-MTB_56427.htm?utm_source=Google&utm_medium=AdwordsProductAds&utm_campaign=Adwords&gclid=COe3_72fkLwCFQQGwwodhk4AMQ) and some just as [F29 Carbon 3](http://www.westbrookcycles.co.uk/cannondale-f29-carbon-3-hardtail-mountain-bike-2013-p210888?gclid=CKzY8LefkLwCFXMbtAodsCQACg).

They're both the same RRP, **but the specs differ**.  I know my question is *what's the difference* and I'm now saying that the specs differ, but I'm no expert on the parts used.

So, is one better than the other or are they just *different/equivalent* parts of roughly equal cost?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They look like the same bike to me. Its just different shops listing them in different ways.

As far as I can tell, the specifications are exactly the same, but those shops have listed the parts in different ways. eg one has listed both hubs together, the other has them separately. And one specifies what saddle it is, the other doesn't. Both shops are showing the same photo.

Checking the [2013 Cannondale website](http://www.cannondale.com/gbr/2013/bikes/mountain/hardtail-29er/f-series-29er), it just lists the F29 CARBON 3, no mention of "Flash". It looks like Flash was a brand used for the 2012 range, but for 2013 it is has been abbreviated to just "F".

Comment: I also don't see the spec difference, either. The Cannondale 2013 model list (http://media.cannondale.com/media/catalogues/cannondaleMountain-2013_usa.pdf) also agrees with their website. In any case, occasionally during the middle of a production run, parts are swapped out for near equivalents in many mass produced things - this happens all the time with cars (for example, some cars at the same trim level will have chrome instead of body color moldings occasionally, or a slightly different radio or something).